# Reorder vertex of a graph. It should be ordered like Petersen graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have next code:

```
import networkx

grafoPetersen = {
    1: [2,5,6], 
    2: [3,1,7], 
    3: [4,2,8], 
    4: [5,3,9], 
    5: [1,4,10],
    6: [1,8,9], 
    7:[2,9,10], 
    8: [3,10,6], 
    9: [4,6,7], 
    10: [5,7,8]
}

for k in grafoPetersen:
    grafoPetersen[k].append(-1)
    grafoPetersen[k].append(-2)
grafoPetersen[-1] = list(range(1,11))
grafoPetersen[-2] = list(range(1,11))

rutaHamiltoniana = [8, 3, 4, 5, 10, 7, 2, 1, 6, 9];
g = networkx.Graph()
for k, vs in grafoPetersen.items():
    for v in vs:
        if v in [-1, -2] or k in [-1, -2]:
            continue
        if abs(rutaHamiltoniana.index(k) - rutaHamiltoniana.index(v)) == 1:
            g.add_edge(k,v, color='red', width=1.5)
        else:
            g.add_edge(k,v, color='black', width=0.5)

posicion = networkx.circular_layout(g)
edges = g.edges()
colores = [g[u][v]['color'] for u,v in edges]
anchuras = [g[u][v]['width'] for u,v in edges]
networkx.draw(g, posicion, edges=edges, edge_color=colores, width=anchuras, with_labels = True)
```

And I get an output like:

[image: Output]

My graph is a Petersen's graph, and I want show it like:

[image: Petersen]

But with same style of I have set in the first pict.

I have tryed it like:

```
options = {
    'with_labels': True,
    'node_color': 'black',
    'node_size': 200,
    'width': 3,
}
networkx.draw_shell(g, nlist=[range(5,10), range(5)], **options)
```

as here suggest: [How to show a graph like a Petersen's graph](http://www.mhenderson.net/graph-drawing/2014/05/02/networkx-01.html) but I get several errors.

Any idea how can I parse first pict into second pict maintaning first pict styles?

---

**EDIT 1:**  Here is full code how I get a path of Petersen's graph and draw it like first pict: [Hamiltonian path inside Petersen's graph algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178527/find-an-hamiltonian-path-inside-the-petersen-subgraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lists within the `nlist` define groupings of nodes that are going to be placed on concentric circles (shells). The nodes are defined by their ID which we defined in the `grafoPetersen`: 1, 2, ..., 10

```
networkx.draw_shell(g, nlist=[range(5,10), range(5)])
```

This call groups nodes `range(5,10)=[5,6,7,8,9]` on one concentric circle and `range(5)=[0,1,2,3,4]` on second concentric circle. There is, however, no node defined in `grafoPetersen` with ID 0. Furthermore, we have defined a node with ID 10, which is not represented by either of the two ranges.

So in order to fix this, we have to fix the ranges:

```
networkx.draw_shell(g, nlist=[range(6,11), range(1,6)])
```

and with all the fancy options:

```
networkx.draw_shell(g, nlist=[range(6,11), range(1,6)], edge_color=colors, width=widths)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# rutaHamiltoniana = [8, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 2, 1, 6, 9]

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 7), dpi=60)
G = nx.petersen_graph()
shells = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
pos = nx.shell_layout(G, shells)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_color="red", with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G,
    pos = pos,
    # list of tuples for hamiltonian path, not list !!!!!
    edgelist = [(8,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,0), (0,7), (7,2), (2,1), (1,6), (6,9), (9,8)],
    width=8,
    alpha=0.5,
    edge_color="blue"
)
```

[image]